# How to read data from a .txt file and use it for an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, txt

This is what is in the .txt file-

1 Alvin 300

2 Brenda 350

3 Chris 250

4 Dana 500

5 Eli 450

6 Faye 320

7 Glen 670

8 Hannah 230

9 Ian 420

10 Jade 380

this is the main part of the code that takes the functions from the other cpp file.

```
int main()
{
    Programmer programmers[MAX_PROGRAMMERS];
    int numProgrammers = 0;
   
    ifstream inputFile( "programmers.txt" ); // declares file stream and opens for input
   
    if( inputFile.good() )
    {
        numProgrammers = readProgrammers( inputFile, programmers, MAX_PROGRAMMERS );
      
        //close the input file because we are done with it
        inputFile.close();
      
        //report on programmers to console
        generateProgrammerReport( cout, programmers, numProgrammers ); // cout passed as an ostream
      
        //report on programmers to a file
        ofstream outputFile("ProgrammerReport.txt");
        generateProgrammerReport( outputFile, programmers, numProgrammers );
        outputFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File not opened properly!!\n\n";
    }
   
    system("pause");
    return 0;
   
}
```

This is the cpp file that holds the functions I also have a .h file that declares all the functions. I'm not sure where to start. I have the base plan with all the functions but I'm not sure how to write each of the functions or really just where to start. Any help would be needed.

```
int readProgrammers( ifstream& inputFile, Programmer programmers[], int maxProgrammers )
{
  int numProgrammers = 0;
  int programmer_id;
  string name;
  int lines; 
  if(inputFile.is_open())
  {
    while (!inputFile.eof() && numProgrammers < maxProgrammers)
    {
      inputFile >> programmers[numProgrammers].programmer_id;
      inputFile >> programmers[numProgrammers].name;
      inputFile >> programmers[numProgrammers].lines;
      numProgrammers++;
    }
  }
    //just a stub!
    return 0;
}

//returns the total of the lines field for all programmers
int calcTotalLines( Programmer programmers[], int numProgrammers )
{
  int totalLine = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < numProgrammers; i++)
  {
    totalLine += programmers[i].lines; 
  }
  
    //just a stub!
    return totalLine;
}

//returns the average lines coded for all programmers as a float
float calcAverageLines( Programmer programmers[], int numProgrammers )
{
  int totalLine;
  calcTotalLines(programmers, numProgrammers);
  int averageLines = 0;
  averageLines = totalLine/numProgrammers;
    //just a stub!
    return averageLines;
}

//return a string containing info for a particular programmer
string generateProgrammerInfo( Programmer theProgrammer )
{
  int programmer_id;
  string name;
  int lines;
  const int SPACING = 5;
  stringstream sout;
  sout << setw(SPACING) << theProgrammer.programmer_id << theProgrammer.name << theProgrammer.lines << endl;
    //just a stub!
    return sout.str();
}

//generate report for all programmers
//call calcTotalLines, calcAverageLines, and generateProgrammerInfo functions
void generateProgrammerReport( ostream& output, Programmer programmers[], int numProgrammers )
{
  int programmer_id;
  string name;
  int lines; 
  Programmer theProgrammer;
  calcTotalLines(programmers, numProgrammers);
  calcAverageLines(programmers, numProgrammers);
  string generateProgrammerInfo( Programmer theProgrammer );
    //just a stub!
    output << "These are all the programmers:";
    for( int i = 0; i < numProgrammers; i++ )
    {
        output << "\nProgrammer info"; //this should output the programmer info for each programmer
    output << generateProgrammerInfo(theProgrammer) << endl;
    
    }
    output << "\nTotal lines = " << calcTotalLines(programmers, numProgrammers); //this should ouptut the total lines
    output << "\nAverage lines = " << calcAverageLines(programmers, numProgrammers); //this should output the average lines
    output << endl;
}
```

The main.cpp file can't be changed but the cpp file can be changed in order to work with the main.cpp file. can't use vectors either.

Comment: seems like that first piece of code has no relationship to anything else

Comment: I only see 2D arrays.  A 3D array is declared as `int cube_data[3][4][5];`

Answer (score 0):

Try using fstream:

```
ifstream file("filename.txt");
string text;
vector<string> lines;

while(getline(file, text)){
    lines.push_back(text);
}
```

And you can do whatever you want with the elements in the vector.

You just have to remember to add this:

```
#include <fstream>
```

at the top.

I hope this answers your question!

Comment: waiting for "we are not allowed to use vector" comment from OP

Comment: dude... i'm just trying to help...

Comment: I am totally with you. Not a criticism of you at all.  So many SO questions we answer using vectors and OP says 'we are not allowed to use vector' which shows really bad c++ teaching

Answer (score 0):

You have a file of *records*.  Each text line is record.
Let's model a record:

```
struct Record
{
  int          person_id;
  std::string  name;
  int          value;
};
```

Let's overload `operator>>` to make reading a record easier:

```
struct Record
{
  int          person_id;
  std::string  name;
  int          value;
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r)
{
    input >> r.person_id;
    input >> r.name;
    input >> r.value;
    input.ignore(10000, '\n');  // Read to end of line for synchronization
    return input;
}
```

The input code could like like this:

```
std::vector<Record> database;
Record r;
while (my_input_file >> r)
{
    database.push_back(r);
}
```

At this point you have an array of records.  You can access fields in a record like:

```
std::cout << "Name from 5th record: " << database[4].name << "\n";
```

When you are thinking of parallel arrays, stop.  Use a `std::vector` of struct and overload `operator>>` to input a record.

Comment: can't use vector

Comment: Take a different C++ course.  You can substitute an array instead of the vector.  You'll have to use dynamic memory since you don't know at compile time, the quantity of input from the User (or declare the array large enough).